# How to change the background color of kendo-ui Dialog in Angular

Tags: css, angular, kendo-ui

I need to change the background color of the pop up, I tried using `[ngStyle]` attribute but, this resulted in the change of the color of the backdrop instead.
 After some hunting I found out that applying background-color attribute to the k-window class changed the bg color of the pop up, But I want it to change based on a condition. I think that we cannot directly add the definition of the class to the condition, it only takes the name of the class.
 Is there any other way to change the background color of the pop up.

I tried something like this.

```
<kendo-dialog [ngClass]="{'k-window{background-color:red}' : flag = true,'k-window{background-color:green}': flag = false">
</kendo-dialog>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a while of trying different solutions, I finally realized that I could change the background color of the kendo-ui dialog in angular by overring the global CSS .

I found out that the class responsible for the change of the color was `k-window-content`

Therefore I overrided it with the use of `::ng-deep .k-window-content{ background-color: 'red'}` , I placed this CSS class inside the component where I wanted it modified.

But soon i realized that , whenever I jumped from this component to another component having the same dialog, the color of that dialog too changed, which I didn't want.

**SOLUTION**
Then i found this solution 
`:host ::ng-deep .k-window-content { background-color: 'red'; }`

By adding `:host` to the class declaration, I was able to limit the change of the background color on for the desired component, without disturbing the dialogs in other components

Answer (score 1):

**Using the ngClass directive for convenience**

```
<div [ngClass]="'example-class'"></div>
```

**NgClass can also assign multiple static class names all at once:**

```
<div [ngClass]="['example-class', 'other-class']"></div>
```

If we want to toggle CSS classes based on a condition, we pass in a JavaScript object. The keys of the object are the class names and the values represent the conditions.

```
<div
  [ngClass]="{
  'example-class': condition
}"
></div>
```

**We can also use ngClass to assign multiple CSS classes based on multiple conditions.**

```
<div
  [ngClass]="{
  'example-class': condition,
  'other-class': !condition
}"
></div>
```

**Try This in Kendo-dialog**

```
<div id="kendo-grid"> 
 <kendo-dialog>
</div>
```

**In CSS File**

```
#kendo-grid .kendo-grid{
 //CSS
}
```

Comment: Question is for `kendo-dialog`. Can you apply it on `kendo-dialog` ?